# promisify redis get and return the correct typescript type

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, node-promisify

The redis method `get` from redis node lib has this typescript signature:

```
export interface Commands<R> {
    get(key: string, cb?: Callback<string | null>): R;
}
```

If I `promisify` the method, the signature is lost and the return type become `any`.

I have tried to set the correct signature in this way:

```
const client = redis.createClient(redisOption);
const getAsync = promisify<redis.Commands<boolean>['get']>(client.get).bind(client);
```

but ts lint show some error:

> Get the value of a key.
>
> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 14, '(fn:
> CustomPromisify<(key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean>):
> (key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean', gave the following
> error.
> Argument of type '(key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomPromisify<(key: string,
> cb?: Callback) => boolean>'.
> Property '**promisify**' is missing in type '(key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean' but required in type
> 'CustomPromisifyLegacy<(key: string, cb?: Callback) =>
> boolean>'.   Overload 2 of 14, '(fn: (callback: (err: any, result:
> (key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean) => void) => void): ()
> => Promise<(key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(callback: (err: any, result:
> (key: string, cb?: Callback) => boolean) => void) => void'.

How set the correct signature?

Comment: Did you solve this issue at the end? Facing a similar problem. Thanks!

Comment: @JavierGuzmán nope...

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue.

Not sure if it's the optimal solution, but what I've done is I extended the RedisClient interface and then overridden the `get` method type.

```
import util from "util";
import redis  from "redis";

interface PromiseRedis extends Omit<redis.RedisClient, "get"> {
  get(key: string): Promise<string | boolean> | boolean;
}

const url = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379";
const redisClient:PromiseRedis = redis.createClient(url);
redisClient.get = util.promisify(redisClient.get)
```

Now the get function returns a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure this out recently:

```
import { Commands, createClient } from 'redis';
import { promisify } from 'util';

type Cmd<T> = Commands<Promise<T>>;
type SET = boolean;
type HSET = number;
type GET = string | null;
type HGETALL = Record<string, string>;
type DEL = number;
type HDEL = number;
type KEYS = string[];

const redis = createClient({});

export type Client = {
  set: Cmd<SET>['set'];
  hset: Cmd<HSET>['hset'];
  get: Cmd<GET>['get'];
  hgetall: Cmd<HGETALL>['hgetall'];
  del: Cmd<DEL>['del'];
  hdel: Cmd<HDEL>['hdel'];
  keys: Cmd<KEYS>['keys'];
};

const set = promisify(redis.set).bind(redis) as Cmd<SET>['set'];
const hset = promisify(redis.hset).bind(redis) as Cmd<HSET>['hset'];
const get = promisify(redis.get).bind(redis) as Cmd<GET>['get'];
const hgetall = promisify(redis.hgetall).bind(redis) as Cmd<HGETALL>['hgetall'];
const del = promisify(redis.del).bind(redis) as Cmd<DEL>['del'];
const hdel = promisify(redis.hdel).bind(redis) as Cmd<HDEL>['hdel'];
const keys = promisify(redis.keys).bind(redis) as Cmd<KEYS>['keys'];

export const client: Client = {
  set,
  hset,
  get,
  hgetall,
  del,
  hdel,
  keys,
};
```

I had tried:

```
type Cmd<T> = Commands<Promise<ReturnType<T>>>;
// ...
const get = promisify(redis.get).bind(redis) as Cmd<typeof redis.get>['get'];
```

To keep it truly generic but it doesn't work. Reason being for example `redis.get` synchronously returns a `boolean` (which I believe refers to the success of the call itself), but the `string` you want to get is returned in the `callback` parameter passed as an argument.